# Track temperature over time

Tags: software-recommendation, power-management, temperature, sensors

Is there an application that lets you track CPU temperature over time?
I am aware of what the sensors app from `lm-sensors` does, but what if I want to compare the heat vs CPU load from N-weeks ago until today?

I might be able to write one in C, but I'm wondering if such software already exists.

Comment: I use Conky as a system monitor and stats are refreshed every second but something's like disk space is updated every minute. You could adapt it to write out temp every 5 minutes or whenever. If you like I can post code tonight as an answer.

Comment: Another option would be a 'cron' job that appends to a log file every 5 minutes which would be a lot simpler than Conky.

Comment: use Netdata. It gives you everything.

Answer (score 5):

We have created a tool that does that called s-tui.
It lets you monitor temperature frequency and CPU utilization over time. You can also save the data to a CSV.

The code is available on github: https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui

This is what a screen shot looks like
[image]

Simplest install with pip (python package manager)

`sudo pip install s-tui`

Install pip if you don't have it

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Installation is also available via ppa, but it does not have the latest versions of the python libraries required.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amanusk/python-s-tui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-s-tui`

Then run `s-tui` or `sudo s-tui`

The key features are:

- Runs in the terminal
- Lets you run a stress test to check system stability (requires `stress` to be installed)
- Track temperature and maximum temperature per session

You can download and run the executable directly

`https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui/releases/
chmod +x s-tui
./s-tui`

All of these instruction are available in the README on github

Comment: Im excited to look into this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple to use monitoring software package [monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/) written in perl. It uses `rrdtool` to keep old data, and provides its own mini web server so you easily browse the graphs of recent activity, see [screenshots](http://www.monitorix.org/screenshots.html).

There is no package for Ubuntu, but since it doesn't need compiling it is fairly simple to install, see [github](https://github.com/mikaku/Monitorix).

It logs cpu temperature and load, and provides separate graphs of these, but I don't know how simple it would be to design your own graph. You could always use [rrdtool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/rrdtool) directly to show the data, but it needs some effort to use properly.

[image: LM-sensors graph]

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a cron job.

1. Make a folder like temp_logs.
2. Place the following file as a shell script in this folder, for example, `temp_logging.sh`. Make the script executable.

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash 
   # Log temperatures of all cores individually.
   # Log temperature over some time using this script run as cron job. 
   # Set your interval given as days, hours, minutes or seconds as the cron job itself.

   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # log might become big, hence remove one line each after 5000 lines.
   lines=$(wc -l < temp_log.txt)
   if ["$lines" -gt 5000 ]
   then
       sed -i '1d' temp_log.txt
   fi
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   #output will be a txt file `temp_log.txt` which will have n columns for n cores and day and time.
   ( sensors | grep -A 0 'Core' | cut -c18-21|xargs | awk '{ sum += $1; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }'  ; sensors | grep -A 0 'Core' | cut -c18-21|xargs; echo $(date +"%m/%d/%Y %T" )) | xargs
   ```
3. Set a cron job to run this script as per your requirement.
   Get log accumulated in the file `temp_log.txt`

For example, for every logging every 5 minutes. then the cron line would be.

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script/temp_logging.sh
```

---

**Output:**
First col is average, next 6 are for individual cores and then day and time.

```
25 25.0 25.0 26.0 25.0 27.0 25.0 06/10/2017 14:54:59
25 25.0 25.0 26.0 25.0 27.0 25.0 06/10/2017 14:55:00
25 25.0 25.0 25.0 25.0 26.0 26.0 06/10/2017 14:55:01
25 25.0 25.0 25.0 25.0 26.0 26.0 06/10/2017 14:55:01
26 26.0 25.0 25.0 25.0 26.0 25.0 06/10/2017 14:55:02
```